# Determine secure url in JSP with spring security

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

Like many websites, I have a login popup on every webpage of my site.  Most of these pages are http (non-secure).  But the login mechanism has to post to a secure url.  All this works great.  The problem is the secure url changes in the various dev environments, staging and different production environments.

So not too big of a deal, I just have a properties file for each environment with the secure host and port.  Now is there a way to encode the url with the right context and jsession id (if needed) and other things c:url normally does?

for example:

```
<form method="post" action="${rootHttpsUrl}/login">
```

I might think this would work to modify the url to add the right context, session info if needed, etc:

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='${rootHttpsUrl}/login'/>">
```

But that doesn't work because c:url sees https://some-url.com and thinks it's an external link.  So I could just modify the url myself:

```
<form method="post"
action="<%=response.encodeURL(${rootHttpsUrl}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login)%>">
```

But escaping to java code like that doesn't let java see the rootHttpsUrl jsp variable (how do I expose this to java?).  Is there a way to call encodeURL from within JSP?

So what's the best solution here?  I'm using Spring, Spring webmvc and Spring Security v3.0.  Ideally there's something like

```
<c:url value='/login' secure='true'/>
```

**UPDATE**: The best I've come up with is to have a properties file for each environment with a property for the https host and port.  Then I add that to the model and reference any secure URL like this:

```
https://${httpsHostAndPort}<c:url value='/login'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard-encode it yourself.

```
action="${rootHttpsUrl}/login;jsessionid=${pageContext.session.id}"
```

Comment: Yes, well we also need the context, but easy enough to add.  However, I don't want the session id exposed unless necessary (cookies not enabled).  I guess I'm at least looking for a standard way to add the session id only when necessary...

Comment: You can use under each [`HttpServletRequest#isRequestedSessionIdFromURL()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isRequestedSessionIdFromURL%28%29) to determine whether the client is passing the session ID around by URL (and thus likely doesn't support cookies).

Comment: That's the same problem with HttpServletRequest#encodeURL, which does all the work for us.  How do I use it inside a JSP page?  I can do a <%= %>, but then I can't access the JSP variable...  or can I?

Comment: You can obtain `${rootHttpsUrl}` in scriptlet using `pageContext.findAttribute("rootHttpsUrl")`. I am although not a fan of scriptlets, but I don't see other ways. Spring guys may know cleaner ways with help of servlet or filter like preprocessing functionality.

Comment: I updated the question with what I think is the best way to implement this

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours of browsing for various alternatives, this page has been really helpful.

My issue was disabling caching of js and css files in my spring secured web application.
But at the same time caching these files "within" a particular session.

Passing a unique id with every request is one of the advised approaches.

And this is what I did :-
Instead of

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```

I used

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/home.js?id=${pageContext.session.id}"></script>
```

Any cons to the above approach are welcome.
Security Issues ?